# callback не работает, при имитации задержки setTimeout

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

Изучаю JS, изучил callback ф-ции, но остался вопрос.
В примерах типа этого:

```
function first(){
// Симулируем задержку кода
setTimeout( function(){
console.log(1);
}, 500 );
}

function second(){
console.log(2);
}

first();
second();

// результат
// 2
// 1
```

Обычно демонстрируют асинхронность js с помощью имитации задержки.
Потом показывают что callback ф-ция решает эту проблему, только имитацию задержки убирают, и непонятно работает оно?.
Я оставил задержку, и у меня код не работает как надо, подскажите почему так?

```
function first(callback) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        console.log(1);
    }, 500);    
    callback();
}

function second() {     
    console.log(2);
}

first(second);

// результат
// 2
// 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у тебя callback вне таймаута, вставь его в таймаут, т.е. разницы между 1 кейсом и вторым у тебя совершенно нет. Да и пример не лучший подобран.

```
let i = 1;
function first(){
    // Симулируем задержку кода
    setTimeout( function(){
         console.log(i);
         i++;
    }, 500 );
}

function second(){
    console.log(i);
}

first();
second();

// результат
// 1
// 1
```

А вот с коллбэком

```
let i = 1;
function first(callback){
    // Симулируем задержку кода
    setTimeout( function(){
         console.log(i);
         i++;
         callback()
    }, 500 );
}

function second(){
    console.log(i);
}

first(second);

// результат
// 1
// 2
```

Comment: ваш пример с коллбэком не работает,
задержка не разделяет вывод 1 и 2

Comment: симуляция задержки происходит не в том месте где надо.

Comment: А, я не совсем понял задачу, в таком случае @AleksanderA
callback как раз юзается в таких случаях, если у тебя есть функция а и функция b, но функция a работает с задержкой, при этом из функции a передаются/изменяются важные данные для функции b и нужно их как-то передать в функцию b, поэтому коллбэком прокидывают функцию b в функцию a, там же можно прокидывать в этот коллбэк нужные тебе аргументы.

Comment: Если ты прокидываешь коллбэк, вне скопа того самого асинхронного кода, то естественно ничего не меняется. @AleksanderA

Comment: @AleksanderA callback не делает асинхронную функцию синхронной. А лишь является прокинутой функцией в асинхронном скопе

Answer (score 0):

разобрался сам.
Код имитирует задержку, ф-ции выполняются синхронно, second дожидается выполнения first:

```
function first(callback) {
    setTimeout( function () {
            console.log('1-start');
            return () => {
                console.log('1-end');
                callback();                     
            }
    }(), 3000);     
}

function second() {     
    console.log('2-start');
}

first(second);
```

При этом callback ни как не влияет на борьбу с асинхронностью, тот же синхронный код, с последовательным выполнением ф-ций, без callback.
first не принимает в себя callback, second дожидается выполнения first:

```
function first() {
    setTimeout( function () {
            console.log('1-start');
            return () => {
                console.log('1-end');
                second();                       
            }
    }(), 3000);     
}

function second() {     
    console.log('2-start');
}

first();
```